# Why is R's sort function so slow for short vectors?

Tags: r, sorting

Why is it that R's `sort` function is so slow for short vectors?  For vectors of length 2 or 3, the below toy implementation of bubblesort is almost an order of magnitude faster than `sort`!

```
bubblesort <- function(x) {
  i <- length(x)
  while (i>1) {
    j <- 1
    while (j<i) {
      if (x[j]>x[j+1])
        x[j+0:1] <- x[j+1:0]
      j <- j + 1
    }
    i <- i - 1
  }
  x
}
x <- runif(10)
bubblesort(x)
#>  [1] 0.07146454 0.20584236 0.21178417 0.54820837 0.60373045 0.71108993
#>  [7] 0.72068104 0.91850898 0.96016281 0.98805395
sort(x)
#>  [1] 0.07146454 0.20584236 0.21178417 0.54820837 0.60373045 0.71108993
#>  [7] 0.72068104 0.91850898 0.96016281 0.98805395
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort(runif(2)),
  bubblesort(runif(2)),
  sort(runif(3)),
  bubblesort(runif(3)),
  sort(runif(10)),
  bubblesort(runif(10)),
  sort(runif(20)),
  bubblesort(runif(20))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>         sort(runif(2)) 30.228 35.6835 44.62655 38.9970 44.0060 191.712   100
#>   bubblesort(runif(2))  2.203  3.2455  4.46545  4.1930  5.2440  10.289   100
#>         sort(runif(3)) 32.843 36.4460 42.65150 38.7410 41.2360 152.067   100
#>   bubblesort(runif(3))  2.555  4.6670  6.89911  5.6525  7.3650  73.671   100
#>        sort(runif(10)) 31.717 37.6945 42.81501 39.0330 43.6345 107.488   100
#>  bubblesort(runif(10)) 13.561 21.6865 27.18694 25.7375 28.5140  97.375   100
#>        sort(runif(20)) 31.761 38.2905 46.33787 40.3975 43.9200 177.757   100
#>  bubblesort(runif(20)) 54.018 78.3025 91.85322 88.0000 99.3935 266.090   100
```

Comment: Probably because sort does a few more things than just sorting. Think of storing that the vector is sorted or not (can check with `is.unsorted(x)` and or using `sort(x, index.return = T)` which only cost like 1/3rd of a second. You can already see that sort becomes very fast way faster as your alternative and that the cost of using sort is just once and constant. It is actually a fun thing you wrote that could even be usefull IF you apply for example over a huge amount of very short numeric vectors that need to be sorted.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg, please post as an answer. (OP: if you needed to sort very short vectors very quickly you could try `base::sort.int()` or even extract some of the guts and skip some of the argument-checking ...)

Comment: @Merijn and @Ben Yes, you're both right.  Looking through the source code it seems that `x[.Internal(radixsort(NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,x))]` is what does the actual sorting

Comment: It's not so much _slow_ for short vectors, as _constant-time_ for short vectors